# Android:how to pass objects from a non-activity (view) class to an activity?

Tags: android

I have a class (Called **Doodling**:))) that extends view and an activity (Called **DrawActivity**) that displays that view. I need to pass the bitmap object created by my doodling class to the draw activity. Is it possible to do that? And if yes,How?!

The code is as below:

```
public class Doodling extends View {
  Bitmap bitmap;

  public DoodleCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    ...
  }

  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap .recycle();
    }
    canvas= new Canvas();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    ...
  }
```

.

```
public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);
  }
```

The doodling view is then placed in the layout via .xml

Comment: Could you use getDrawingCache method on your view?

Comment: I think i can.but thats not the problem,i have the bitmap object,i just dunno how to pass it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this: `I need to pass the bitmap object created by my doodling class to the draw activity`

Comment: I need to save the bitmap of the drawing,and load it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that Doodling will only be used in DrawActivity, then you can obtain a reference to the Activity using `getSystemService()`.

```
public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private static final String TAG = "DrawActivity";

     public static DrawActivity get(Context context) {
           // noinspection ResourceType
           return (DrawActivity)context.getSystemService(TAG);
     } 

     @Override 
     public Object getSystemService(String name) {
          if(TAG.equals(name)) return this ;
          return super.getSystemService(name);
     }
```

And

```
 public class Doodle extends View {
      .... 
          DrawActivity drawActivity = DrawActivity.get(getContext());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? what is TAG? and does using this code mean i will have access to drawactivity methods in doodlig?

Comment: Whoops I missed adding TAG field

Answer (score 0):

In your `DrawActivity` create a new instance of your `Doodling` class.
Then use the following code :-

```
doodlingObject.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            doodlingObject.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = doodlingObject.getDrawingCache();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will add hard way to achieve this butI will suggest you to use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) for much more cleaner uses and not worrying about interfaces or activity life cycle

You can do this using interfaces if you have created View object from activity itself

Something like:

```
interface BitMapListener{
 void onBitMapCreated(Bitmap bMap);
}
```

then this interface to implement this in Activity

```
public DrawActivity ... implements BitMapListener{
 BitMap created;
 @override
 public void onBitMapCreated(BitMap map){
    created = map;
 }
 //when calling DrawView activity pass in this object
 //DrawView(DrawActivity.this);
```

Just when calling DrawView class from activity remember to passin this activity object like :

```
DrawView ...{
 DrawActivity callback;
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
if (bitmap != null) {
    bitmap .recycle();
}
canvas= new Canvas();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
callback.onBitMapCreated(bitmap);
}
```